# Transition from bar chart to scatter chart. Run-time error 1004

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I want to ask a question on how to solve this code to transition from bar chart to scatter plot in Excel VBA.

```
Sub AnimateTransition()
Dim BarChart As ChartObject
Dim ScatterChart As ChartObject
Dim BarDataRange As Range
Dim ScatterDataRange As Range
Dim Counter As Long
Dim TotalCount As Long

' Set the ranges for bar chart data and scatter plot data
Set BarDataRange = Range("F2:H9")
Set ScatterDataRange = Range("A14:B18")

' Get the total count of data points in the bar chart range
TotalCount = BarDataRange.Cells.Count

' Create the bar chart
Set BarChart = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=200, Width:=400, Top:=50, Height:=300)
BarChart.Chart.SetSourceData BarDataRange

' Set the initial appearance of the scatter chart
Set ScatterChart = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=BarChart.Left, Width:=BarChart.Width, Top:=BarChart.Top, Height:=BarChart.Height)
ScatterChart.Chart.ChartType = xlXYScatter
ScatterChart.Chart.SetSourceData ScatterDataRange
ScatterChart.Visible = False

' Transition from bar chart to scatter chart
For Counter = 1 To TotalCount
    Sleep (80)
    DoEvents
    BarChart.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(Counter).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255) ' Change bar color
    ScatterChart.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(Counter).MarkerStyle = xlMarkerStyleDiamond
Next Counter

' Make the scatter chart visible
ScatterChart.Visible = True
ScatterChart.Parent.Visible = True

' Remove the bar chart
BarChart.Delete
End Sub
```

The line:

ScatterChart.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(Counter).MarkerStyle = xlMarkerStyleDiamond

Keeps encountering error like run-time error 1004. Parameter is not valid.

Any help is appreciated thank you so much!

Comment: `BarDataRange` has more cells then `ScatterDataRange` so your loop runs out of points in the scatter plot